# Python data plotting using turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Any idea on how to plot this data in a list as a bar graph?

```
freqList = [0.09090909090909091, 0.0, 0.0, 0.09090909090909091, 0.18181818181818182, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.045454545454545456, 0.18181818181818182, 0.045454545454545456, 0.09090909090909091, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.045454545454545456, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

the numbers represent occurrences of a letter: a-z

I need the letter value on the x-axis(a - z) and the frequency on the y(0 - 1.00.

```
def letterFreqPlot(freqList):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    screen = t.getscreen()
    screen.setworldcoordinates(0,0,25,1.00)
    t.goto(0,0)
```

Comment: With turtle? Lol. Haven't seen this before. Do you really need to use turtle?

Comment: Yeah it has to be turtle : )

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over the elements in `freqList`

```
t.goto(0,0)
for item in freqList:
    t.forward(1)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(item)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(1)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(item)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(1)
```

Noticing the obvious repetition you can simplify by nesting another loop

```
t.goto(0,0)
for item in freqList:
    for dist in [1, item, 1, item]:
        t.forward(dist)
        t.left(90)
    t.forward(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, do you know what would be the simplest way to label each bar with A, B, C etc..and the frequencies?

Comment: @Adam, yes use `t.write()`